# What is the voltage of LED string when not conducting?

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

Simply put, what's the voltage at the end of an LED string if the low side MOSFET is switched off. In other words, what must the FET voltage rating be. Note that I'm not asking on exact answer on this particular type of LED and voltage/current in that schematic. It's just to demonstrate the idea.

In my actual circuit I'm driving 20x high power white LEDs at 40mA. Vf=6V. Mosfet leakage current is 0.1µA at 25C and 1µA at 125C.

So when I switch off the bottom MOSFET, is it going to see

1. zero volts
2. 120 volts
3. something in-between like 120V - 20 x 3v
       (effective zero current forward voltage) = 60V?

[image: low side high voltage LED current control]

**Conclusion**
I performed a simple test using 60Vbr Mosfet with 2k2 resistor in series with source and the gate tied to GND.

The voltage will rise to the MOSFET breakdown voltage presuming it's less than the LED bar input voltage. However the current flow is practically zero as no avalanche can develop as the LEDs are firmly below any sensible threshold voltage. Regarding if this can damage the FET or not, I'd hazard the answer is "no", presuming the Vbr is large enough that the LEDs will not conduct meaningful current at the remaining voltage.

Comment: Measure it? Empirical data ftw

Comment: Vf(Id=0) = 0, 120V with high source resistance.

Comment: @Passerby I was leaning on that direction as well but we get into territory of very high impedances, funky things start happening. What happens when I stick the multimeter probe in??

Comment: The multimeter will be 10 M ohms. That's very likely **less** than the **off** resistance of the NMOS. If you'd stick the meter across the LEDs, the voltage across the LEDs might actually drop. When you'd stick the meter across the NMOS, the voltage might actually drop as well. You could do it using a Wien-Bridge type circuit, meter between drain of NMOS and bridge then adjust for V=0 then measure on bridge. That's cumbersome though.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It was a rhetorical question :-)

Comment: Eh, good enough for practical purposes, no?

Comment: @Passerby Not so fast. 1µA leakage current at 120V implies 120Mohm resistance over the mosfet. You stick the ~10Mohm multimeter parallel to the mosfet and you're dramatically changing the circuit impedance.  If we're being nitpicky the 60V mosfet I gave as an example might very well go *poof* if the leakage current of the LEDs is significantly more than the 0.1-1µA

Comment: If the FET is rated for >120V then leakage current applies and you wouldnt be asking this question, so Vbr spec of 1mA applies and my answer is still correct , meanwhile your question is wrong

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The entire question can be summarized "Do I need voltage rating equal of the LED string Anode terminal" or not. Your answer is "yes" obviously. If we want to stick to the IPD220N06, it's an avalanche rated MOSFET and would obviously work in this case. But since I'm interested if I'm overspecifying the components..

Comment: Check in the datasheet the mosfet off resistance, then measure the current, apply the ohm's law and you're done.

Comment: I've just simulated it out with the ltspice and it's around 120 V. I've used the BSC123N08NS3 nmos, with If<0.3 nA. If you tell me the real nmos and leds I can tell you the exact value of current and voltage.

Comment: @judoka_acl Excellent, thank you! I love it when someone does my job for me! I've used IPD220N06 as an example here but that's 60V DS and avalanche rated so it should clip the voltage @ 60V if the model is correct. Try SIB452DK instead: http://www.vishay.com/product?docid=68832, white LED is Lumiled Luxeon DW3014 2.5 but I can't give you the datasheet.   Any LED connected in series enough to reach 120Vf should simulate the situation well enough.

Comment: if you keep enough secrets in the question, it becomes rhetorical or worse. Neither  FETs will be stressed in this case but with 60V/20/2 = 1.5V  so if you want to bypass the LED current use a pullup R across LEDs with a value of 60V/250uA =240k  (60mW when ON)  https://www.lumileds.com/uploads/459/DS208-pdf shows only 3V LED

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Wrong LED. And 240k in series with the FET would give you voltage division of 240k/120M or worse.

Comment: What is your exact PN. This is the spec for the 3014 series.  240k pullup will raise Vds to 60Vbr @240uA or similar or 120V @ 500uA. Do we have to continue guessing what you actually want to know? (without specs)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Luxeon DW3014 2.5 as mentioned above. Or DW3014 2D but makes no difference. WRT transistor, I misread the datasheet. 0.1µA and 1µA are not leakage currents at 25C and at 125C, it's typical and max at 25C. At 125C it can go up to 100µA. If you put 240k in series with 1µA leakage current component at 120V, effective voltage over mosfet would be 119.8V. Obviously it'll breakdown and the voltage settles to 60V but you can't go around overloading non-avalanche-rated components, can you now?

Comment: If your FET spec is the right one, you are NOT overloading the FET. Try again.  VDS = 190 V, VGS = 0 V, TJ = 55 °C 10uA yet Vds will never exceed 120v such as with a 240k pullup. even if leakage was 100uA, Vds still does not exceed 190V

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 In which case we'd conclude the MOSFET drain sees the voltage at the other end of the LED string when switched off (Option "2"). And the low-side MOSFET would have to be rated above voltage driving the LED string.

Comment: This is what we call a fallacious circular argument.  Read the specs for Vbr(ds)@Irated and show me a power fet with one rated < 500uA at whatever Vbr 60V +/-

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That specification doesn't mean you're _allowed_ to drive 1mA at 60Vds, it means the MOSFET won't _conduct_ more than 1mA at 60Vds and 0Vgs. Non-avalanche rated MOSFET might be damaged when the parasitic capacitances discharge above the avalanche threshold. With roughly 400k power MOSFETs being subject to this every day it's not necessarily a happy equation even if it's highly unlikely.

Comment: I disagree @barleyman the LED capacitance and leakage will not damage the power FET Vbr ratings even without avalanche protection unless your line inductance is very high. Adding a cap or snubber load is simple protection.  Again more circular arguments without valid specs.

Comment: @judoka_acl I really doubt that LTSpice accurately simulates the MOSFET in the subthreshold region...

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 EE isn't an argument. It's based on physics. Also, money, MTBF and such.

Comment: Gents, I did the little science experiment @Passerby suggested except with placing a 2.2k resistor in series with mosfet drain and measuring voltage drop over that to determine the avalanche current. I can conclude that the voltage will in fact rise to the mosfet breakdown voltage but the actual avalanche current is neglible i.e. <1µA.

Comment: Since physics, cost and MTBF is based on adhering to the specs, I conclude my answer is still correct, since my prediction held true that it is from exceed the Vbr current specs and that Vf result c) is the correct answer, similar to what I calculated.

Comment: If you still think my answer is wrong then which spec or calculation is wrong in my assumptions given that you were not forthcoming with specs.

Comment: Specs of a particular part are irrelevant. I use the result to pick whatever part I decide is fit to do the job on whatever LED circuit (including the LED) I decide is the best match for the application. The voltage rises to Vbr level without avalanche current going anywhere _near_ the "Vbr current spec". The behavior unlikely to change regardless of the specific LED or MOSFET used while LEDs will not turn on with the remainder voltage.

Comment: @next-hack are you kidding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So when I switch off the bottom MOSFET, is it going to see a) zero volts b) 120 volts c) something in-between like 120V - 20 x 3v (effective zero current forward voltage) = 60V?*

I would say 120 Volts, when the LEDs are off you basically get a resistive voltage divider of all the LEDs in series against the off resistance of the NMOS. I'm quite sure that the NMOS will "win" (have a higher resistance) so the voltage will develop across the NMOS.

Note that since no current flows, the LEDs will behave as a resistor and/or leak some current. And no current can flow as the NMOS prevents it.

The LEDs will not be able to drop the voltage as for that, some current would have to flow, which the NMOS prevents.

Comment: Well, that was my thinking as well. Unfortunately the static nature of MOSFET could "pop" with essentially zero current static overload voltage. On the other hand semiconductors have nonzero threshold voltage even if you have 0.1µA or something.

Comment: I don't get that last sentence, do you mean that you think current will flow (0.1uA) when \$V_{gs}=0\$?

Comment: MOSFETs have nonzero leakage current. For example IPD220N06L has 0.1µA at 25C and 1µA at 125C.

Comment: Sure but that IPD220N06L would be a really bad choice for this circuit, Vds too low, Vt is quite low, Id,max is 30 A that's far too large. If you'd choose an NMOS with Vt > 4 V, Id,max = 1A and Vds,max = 100V then Id in off would be much, much lower.

Comment: That's actually a Mosfet I use for another LED circuit entirely, it was just a datasheet I had on hand. That particular application is max 55V, 450mA. If you want a low Rth for the Mosfet you're going to end up with these large current figures. On LED low side current control you can easily dissipate 1-2W on that Mosfet and therefore you need low thermal resistance.

Comment: *If you want a low Rth for the Mosfet you're going to end up with these large current figures* But do you really **need** that low Rth? LinearTech uses a Si2328DS in the devboard of that LT3756, that's a 1A NMOS, Rdson is 0.195 ohm typ. At your 40 mA that's 0.3 mW. The NMOS will barely raise its temperature. No reason for Rth to be low at all.

Comment: Don't confuse Rth AKA thermal resistance from junction to case and RDSon which is entirely different. When you dissipate 2W on that MOSFET when using it as a linear current regulator with 6cm^2 copper area, you get 40K/W thermal resistance. But this is all besides the point.

Comment: Oh don't worry, I know the difference between Rth and Rdson. How do you get to the conclusion that you would dissipate 2 W in that NMOS? Here the MOSFET is uses as a PWM switch hence it is on or off, either way it will dissipate very little. But say I confused Rdson with Rth that's not going to change the 0.3 mW of dissipation. I think you're falling in the trap that you think you need the best value for parameter X while you have not actually calculated what you **really** need. Your current is only 40 mA so having a low Rdson is rather **pointless**.

Comment: LED bar current is regulated, hence the MOSFET acts as a linear regulator. 2W is a bit of an outlier but 1W you can end up easily as we're driving 8 LED bars off a single SMPS. It's actually constant current too so more heat for the poor MOSFET. This still has nothing to do with the question :-)

Comment: It does relate to the question because you **think** you need a large MOSFET for dissipation but it is PWM controlled (in the schematic as shown above) so you don't. That allows you a wider choice of MOSFET. *LED bar current is regulated, hence the MOSFET acts as a linear regulator.* That is not true for the circuit in your question!

Comment: True, it isn't. Somewhat misleading but I actually did say it's just an example of the type of arrangement I mean. And WRT IPD220N06L I said _That's actually a Mosfet I use for another LED circuit entirely_. If you're interested in that circuit we can continue it in chat..

Comment: @Barleyman I have characterized many power MOSFETs and, to my surprise, their off-state drain current is orders of magnitude smaller that the typically specified \$1\ \mu A\$. The worst one had between several hudreds pA and 1 nA. The best one had less than 500fA.

Comment: @next-hack Actually the less the leakage current, the higher the voltage rises in the drain. Anyways this answer is mostly correct. There's a single error in reasoning - The voltage will stabilize to the MOSFET breakdown voltage but since the LEDs are not remotely properly conducting at that point, the avalanche current is neglible.

Comment: @Barleyman I wasn't questioning the answer, just the value of the current :) Really I got surprised when I measured such devices!

Comment: @Barleyman there is a fallacy in your reasoning. " Unfortunately the static nature of MOSFET could "pop" with essentially zero current static overload voltage" There is never a zero uA pop failure.   Failure can occur by ESD or  is if there is a flyback current pulse, Since the LEDs will have more capacitance than the switch after turn off, the unknown is the line inductance and its effect with LdI/dt from diode current fall time. So if you were concerned about an unprotected MOSFET with an inductive line, then you would choose a MOSFET with protection included or added..

Answer (score -1):

*20 Vf=6V LEDs at 40mA.* ?? are these 5mm LED's being over driven?

Like Zener's and MOSFETs Vgs(th) there is a threshold voltage at some minimal leakage current.

For White (or blue), it is approx 2.7V near 1mA then Zzt or ESR causes Vf to rise above 2.85V for just about any power rated according to my Rule of thumb ESR~1/Pd.

Red/Yellow Vth=1.7, B/W, 2.7 somewhat like Silicon is ~<0.6V for low current. and 0.65 nom and above defines ESR of the PN junction approx 1/Pd rated for size.

### conclusion

3) in between  (assuming Vin max=120V and 20Wh LEDs, Vd=...)
120V-20*2.6=**68V**

**You can use 3V for a ballpark number for White LEDs when conducting and 2.6V when not conducting for <1% of If or If=1mA, the typical conducting current rating for MOSFET zero bias breakdown voltage.**

Comment: High power white LEDs. Specs as quoted.. One package actually has two dies in series, hence 6V each. On simple diode the forward voltage drops lower than you might think when the current drops to microamp range.

Comment: No datasheet quoted. I never said uA. Don't assume you know what I do.

Comment: I'm not at liberty to share actual LED datasheet and it should be irrelevant which exact type it is.

Comment: The question you should have asked is what is the Vf for the MOSFET spec of V (BR)DSS Drain-source breakdown
voltage Vgs = 0, Id = 1 mA then my answer is still correct. forget about uA.  Do you understand yet?

Comment: Leakage current of mosfet is not 1mA, it's <= 1µA.

Comment: Doh! I said Vdss breakdown voltage current spec

Comment: At 1mA the LEDs would already conduct properly and hence take majority of the voltage. I take it your answer is option "2" i.e. MOSFET is subject to the full 120V voltage when it's turned off (Vgs=0).

Comment: wrong.  read the datasheet specs 1mA will not be 3.0V for Vf of any white LED

Comment: True, it isn't. It's more like 5.25V.

Comment: only if two LEDs in series or 2.6/LED which is why you shud supply more info in your question

Comment: Well, I supply "Vf=6V", right there, which implies it must be dual die configuration. Even if it wasn't, you'd then need 2x of the amount of LEDs to reach that 120Vin and change effectively nothing.

Comment: OK now that you indicate it is in fact a 2S LED with 20x per string, Off state voltage will be 5.25V@1mA *20 = 105V so Vds=15V @1mA so if Vds Max is >> 15V then Vbr(ds) will not be reached and I leakage applies so Voltage will rise as LED Vf drops to 5V or less then Vds=20V or slightly more. so choose Vds(rated) >30V will be no problem.